# Laravel 7 Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Tags: deployment, composer-php, laravel-7, runtimeexception, laravel-facade

I have looked at several answers suggested to a similar issue but nothing worked in my case.
FYI, this is my first project in Laravel 7, working fine on my Mac.
I have deployed the project on my server following [this article](https://laravelarticle.com/deploy-laravel-on-shared-hosting).
When running the project on the web, I get the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258
>
> Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(425): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...', Array) #1 /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(402): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths() #2 /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(313): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException)) #3 /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(210): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExcepti in /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 258

How can I fix it?

Comment: It might be a permission error, I don't know maybe SELinux error, did you try to disable it temporary like `> setenforce 0 ` if you are using centos you can search for the cmd if you are using other OS

Comment: run the  ```php artisan optimize ``` in console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a solution that worked in my case.

1. delete the folder vendor
2. run `composer update`
3. run `php artisan config:cache`
4. run `php artisan config:clear`

Home page now displays but the routes do not work...

Answer (score 1):

If the solution from @Paul Godard doesn't work, it could be a `psr/log` issue as mine.

My `composer update` added `psr/log` v2.0.0, which [requires php8](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/log#2.0.0). However, my application is on php7.4

That gave me the exact error output like in the description

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /usr/www/users/utopiqwvpw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258
```

**My solution was** to specify in `composer.json` that I'm using `"psr/log": "^1.1.0"`

Then run `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when laravel has some errors at php level, like in the case of undefined constants in configuration files until the application even gets bootstrapped. In my case, I had "Undefined constant Redis::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY" in config/database.php. To solve that we have to install php redis module along with igbinary serializer for example.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error when my config folder was deleted by mistake. So after recovering the config folder. My project worked fine. You have to check if any folder is removed on which project is depending. Recover or copy it. It will work fine then.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the way from all forum but none of them work, finally I resolve the issue.

Just rename your **config** folder as config_backup
and just copy the config from a fresh Laravel project and paste it in your project folder then it will resolve.