# How to use Laravel Facades

Tags: php, laravel, production

I have this error bellow happening. I have tried changing same things as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651516/laravel-7-fatal-error-uncaught-runtimeexception-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set), but I had no success.

> Blockquote
> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/concordia/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:236 Stack trace: #0
> Blockquote

I am using Laravel 5.8 and the project doesn't work on production, but on dev it's all fine. Any of you know what this is?

Thanks you a lot.

Comment: How you call the facades?

Comment: I call them in the controllers, but I actually don't know what this error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the vendor folder `rm -rf ./vendor` then install the project dependencies `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`

Also don't forget to set the environment to production and to disable debugging in the `.env` file since you are installing for production

```sh
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Haven't tried yet, but I think it'll work.