# Laravel 9 upgrade from 8 led to PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

The full error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:334`

The project is working fine on localhost. I have already tried deleting the vendor directory and running `composer update` then `composer artisan config:cache` followed by `composer artisan config:clear`. These haven't changed anything. I mention this because it is a solution for a similar error after someone updated to Laravel 8.

The project is running on cPanel is that is relevant and there was also an error prior to this stating Composer requires PHP 8.1.0 which has occured a few times before and been fixed with `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`.

Before the update everything was working fine on this server as well so I can't even rationalize what I may have messed up. Please find the complete error log generated at the root of the public folder on page load below:

```
[14-Jul-2022 16:11:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:334
Stack trace:
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/RegisterErrorViewPaths.php(18): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...', Array)
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(626): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\RegisterErrorViewPaths->__invoke()
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(607): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths()
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(538): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException))
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(444): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(363): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderExceptionResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ParseError))
#6 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(427): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ParseError))
#7 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(115): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->renderException(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ParseError))
#8 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 {main}
  thrown in /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 334
[14-Jul-2022 16:11:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:334
Stack trace:
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/RegisterErrorViewPaths.php(18): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...', Array)
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(626): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\RegisterErrorViewPaths->__invoke()
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(607): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths()
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(538): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException))
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(444): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(363): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderExceptionResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ParseError))
#6 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(427): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ParseError))
#7 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(115): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->renderException(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ParseError))
#8 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 {main}
  thrown in /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 334
```

This is the Laravel log file.

```
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:207)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(132): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL, NULL)
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(119): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(636): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(275): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('syntax error, u...', Array)
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(415): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(ParseError))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->reportException(Object(ParseError))
#6 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected token ")" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected token \")\" at /home/project/project/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:588)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/project/...')
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(88): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(65): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(153): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(137): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:207)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(132): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL, NULL)
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(119): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(636): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(275): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('syntax error, u...', Array)
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(415): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(ParseError))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->reportException(Object(ParseError))
#6 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected token ")" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected token \")\" at /home/project/project/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:588)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/project/...')
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(88): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(65): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(153): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(137): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:207)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(132): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL, NULL)
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(119): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(636): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(275): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('syntax error, u...', Array)
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(415): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(ParseError))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->reportException(Object(ParseError))
#6 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected token ")" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected token \")\" at /home/project/project/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:588)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/project/...')
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(88): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(65): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(153): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(137): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:207)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(132): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL, NULL)
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(119): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(636): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(275): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('syntax error, u...', Array)
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(415): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(ParseError))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->reportException(Object(ParseError))
#6 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 {main}
"} 
[2022-07-14 18:48:22] laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected token ")" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected token \")\" at /home/project/project/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:588)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/project/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/project/...')
#1 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(88): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(65): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#3 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#4 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(153): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(137): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home/project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/project/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 {main}
"}
```

This is my current `app.php` file at the moment, it used to be populated A LOT more than this so I don't know where Laravel 9 has moved the associated packages because its working fine on localhost.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

$app->register(Artesaos\SEOTools\Providers\SEOToolsServiceProvider::class);

return $app;
```

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801263/7574023) ??

Comment: delete the folder `vendor` and run `compser update`

Comment: @boolfalse Yes I have, first question I came across actually

Comment: @JEJ I have already done that, no dice.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @geertjanknapen The server's latest version of PHP is showing 8.1

Comment: Have you written custom facades?

Comment: Also, make sure the facades are registered in `config/app.php` and could you include a log from `laravel.log` from where the error is triggered and then the whole stack trace after?

Comment: @geertjanknapen Great idea, let me check and post the log immediately.

Comment: @geertjanknapen I haven't written any custom facades and as for checking whether facades are registered in `config/app.php`, could you kindly elaborate on how to check for this? Although I would imagine if they weren't registered the project would also not be working on localhost either, right? And its working just fine on localhost.

Comment: They should in `config/app.php` all the way at the bottom. Should look like `'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
    ])->toArray(),`

Comment: Where the commented out part is custom and you should not have

Comment: Looking at logs, are you doing something with the `Log` class

Comment: @geertjanknapen, Huh, that is weird. Actually, now that you mention it my app.php used to be like that but it's almost blank now, I attributed it to the migration to 9. Let me post it so you can advise. Luckily I have a BitBucket repo so I'll try rolling back the changes on `app.php` and report back.... As for the `Log` class I have no idea why its even showing that cause I haven't touched it.

Comment: I just had this issue, been fighting it for about 2 days now.  Works on my local, breaks on server environment.  Server Admin installed PHP 8.1.9 cli, but not the httpd module.  My issue was Laravel upgrade from 5.2 - 9 with a full backend upgrade.  Don't know if it helps ...  But if it does, glad to share...